# Having one column in R with 205550 values, and wanting 10 columns where value 1 goes to column 1, and value 2 goes to column 2 etc

Tags: r, multiple-columns, data-manipulation

My data frame currently looks something like this:

```
        pred
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.01
        0.91
```

where there are 205550 values where rows 1:10 should apply to observation 1, rows 11:20 should apply to observation 2, and so on and so forth from that point on. So I am looking for a way to turn that data table into something like this:

```
       V1    V2      V3      V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9     V10
       0.01  0.01    0.01    0.01   0.01   0.01   0.01   0.01   0.01   0.01
```

If anyone has any helpful suggestions, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You need `df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(dat$pred, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE))`

Comment: It tells me this error, "error in working$pred : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Nevermind I got it working, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different solution using the dplyr package. First, I make the future "rows", and then the future columns. Then I "pivot" the table using the pivot_wider function.

```
dat<-data.frame(pred=1:10000) 


df1<-dat %>%
  mutate(row=ceiling(row_number()/10)) %>%
  mutate(col=paste0("V",row_number() %%10)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from=pred) %>%
  select(-row)
```